# Como Formatar/separar data e Hora de uma campo datetime do sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Tenho a tabela Lançamentos com os seguintes campos:

```
CREATE TABLE [LANCAMENTO](
  [ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  [VALOR] DECIMAL(8, 2), 
  [DATE_BUY] DATETIME, 
  [DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(150), 
  [TYPE_RELEASE] VARCHAR(1), 
  [ORGANIZATION] VARCHAR(50), 
  [ID_USUARIO] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES USUARIOS([ID]));
```

Quero saber como pegar somete a **Hora** ou a **Data** da campo `DATE_BUY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do SQLite](http://fhttps://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) as funções `date()`, `time()` e `datetime()` podem ser escritas em termos da função `strftime()`. Logo, para fazer o que você quer, a consulta é a seguinte:

```
SELECT
   strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date_buy) as data,
   strftime('%H:%M:%S', date_buy) as hora
FROM
   lancamento
```

Em data você terá o formato: **yyyy-mm-dd** e em hora o formato **hh:mm:ss**.

Comment: eu ate tentei fazer assim só que acho que fiz algo errado. Sua resposta foi 10 Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

%Y é para anos %m é para meses e %d é para os Dias
  %H é para as Horas %M é para os minutos e %S é para os segundos

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) as data,
       strftime('%H:%M:%S', date) as hora
FROM lancamento
```